# Search Binary Tree in Python (In-order traversal error)

Tags: python, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I have a theoretical question and as well small mistake, so I am calling inorder_traversal function which was supposed to order the binary tree an it gives me an error **inorder_traversal() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given**. I gave zero arguments and I called zero arguments. So that is the first question and the second one ism so this inorder_traversal function, how does it go from the furthest left up. I didn't quite catch that last part?

```
class BinarySearchTree:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.value = value
        
    def insert(self, value):
        #checking if value that we are trying to insert is less then the current value
        if value < self.value:
            if self.left is None:
                #if the left node is not existing then we are going to create it
                self.left = BinarySearchTree(value)
            else:
                self.left.insert(value)
        else:
            if self.right is None:
                self.right = BinarySearchTree(value)
            else:
                self.right.insert(value)
    def inorder_traversal():
        if self.left:
            self.left.inorder_traversal()
        print(self.value)
        if self.right:
            self.right.inorder_traversal()
        
            
tree = BinarySearchTree(15)
tree.insert(14)
tree.insert(20)
tree.insert(7)
tree.insert(8)
tree.insert(1)
tree.insert(70)
tree.inorder_traversal()
```

Comment: ``inorder_traversal`` should probably be an instance method. As such you need to write ``def inorder_traversal(self):`` (notice the ``self`` argument).

Answer (score 1):

For the first question the answer is that if you called an instance method in python then a self object is passed as an argument to the function so you need to include that parameter in your class function:

```
def inorder_traversal(self):
```

This line:

```
tree.inorder_traversal()
```

Is equivalent to:

```
BinarySearchTree.inorder_traversal(tree)
```

And for the second question you can see this video on youtube it explains the different traversal ordering of binary trees:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-b2lciNd2L4